# CDI: Ambiguous dependencies with only one producer

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm getting these errors when I'm trying to deploy my web application:

> Ambiguous dependencies for type AuthzInfo with qualifiers @Default\n  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField]
>
> Possible dependencies: \n  - Producer Method [AuthzInfo] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @RequestScoped

I've only created a producer like that:

```
@Produces @RequestScoped
public AuthzInfo getAuthzInfo(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) 
    //...
}
```

And I'm using that using `@Inject annotation`:

```
@Inject private AuthzInfo authzInfo;
```

However, I've created a `@CurrentUser` annotation, and I've tagged both `@Producer @CurrentUser` and `@Inject @CurrentUser` using this annotation. The problem have been solved.

Why do I need to user this work around? There is only one producer that producer an `AuthInfo` object.

Answer (score 1):

Your producer method returns `AuthzInfo` but `AuthzInfo` itself is a CDI managed bean. That's why it's ambiguous and a qualifier is required in this situation.

---

You are probably using `bean-discovery-mode="all"` in your `beans.xml`.

If you change to `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` ([default in CDI 1.2 and no `beans.xml` is required](http://www.cdi-spec.org/news/2014/04/14/CDI-1_2-released/)), only classes with a *bean defining annotation* will be discovered, ignoring all other classes:

> [**2.5.1. Bean defining annotations**](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)
>
> A bean class may have a bean defining annotation, allowing it to be
>   placed anywhere in an application, as defined in [Bean Archives](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive). A bean
>   class with a bean defining annotation is said to be an implicit bean.
>
> The set of bean defining annotations contains:
>
> - `@ApplicationScoped`, `@SessionScoped`, `@ConversationScoped` and
>     `@RequestScoped` annotations,
> - all other normal scope types,
> - `@Interceptor` and `@Decorator` annotations,
> - all stereotype annotations (i.e. annotations annotated with
>     `@Stereotype`),
> - and the `@Dependent` scope annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your approach. It have sense. However, I don't have any `beans.xml`.

Comment: @Jordi So you are using CDI 1.2?